# Adding viewController views to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

Despite the number of similar posts on this, I still am having trouble making this work correctly.
I have a two UIViewControllers which I have designed in IB with UILabels and imageviews, etc.
I would like to add these to a scroll view so they can be paged between.

I have outlets defined connecting each of the scrollViewcontrollers with their elements in IB, however, the controllers themselves, I am programatically creating from within the master view controller in viewDidLoad. After creating them, I assign some values from the master view controller than add it as a subview to the scrollViewController. However nothing displays. From the debugging i have done, when I set a break point after assigning the values, I can see that the elements are nil. They should be loaded from the xib file, but it does not seem to be read. Even as a test, I tried initializing one of the elements (eg. UILabel) and setting it to that sub view controller, but it nothing would display. Here is some code to explain a bit better.

In the master view controller

```
    detailControllerA *tempA = [[detailControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailOverviewA" bundle:nil];
    self.overviewA = tempA;
[tempA release];
self.overviewA.someLabel.text = @"Some Text";
    detailScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);
    detailScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

[detailScrollView addSubview:self.overviewA.view];
```

In the detailControllerA implementation I set the frame in loadView:

```
-(void)loadView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 90)];
    self.view = view;
    [view release];

}
```

I also have the labels, etc defined with IBOutlets in detailControllerA.h and implemented to the elements in the xib file.

Any ideas why the xib is not loading correctly when created programatically?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to call [super loadView] before doing anything. Even though you loaded from nib I'm sure loadView is still some how required to create your view in the controllers.

Comment: I figured it out now,
Interestingly enough, the -(void)loadView was the problem.

Since the view is being generated in interface builder (with the frame settings), when loadView fires, it was creating a new view, blowing away the one created in interface builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
       NSUInteger scrollContentCount = 0;

       for (NSUInteger arrayIndex = 0; 
             arrayIndex < [contents count]; 
             arrayIndex++) {


        // set scorllview properties
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.mScrollView.frame.size.width * arrayIndex;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.mScrollView.frame.size;

        myScrollView.autoresizingMask = YES;

        // alloc - init PODetailsView Controller
        myController = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [myController.view setFrame:frame];

        // add view in scroll view
        [self.myScrollView addSubview:myController.view];

        scrollContentCount = scrollContentCount + 1;
    }

// set scroll content size
self.myScrollView.contentSize = 
    CGSizeMake(self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * scrollContentCount, 
                         self.myScrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Don't release the content controller object which is in for-loop.

Set your ***scrollView contentSize*** according to your requirement.

Hope this would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, the -(void)loadView was the problem.

Since the view is being generated in interface builder (with the frame settings), when loadView fires, it was creating a new view, blowing away the one created in interface builder.